# CineRAID CR-H458

Tags: raid, compatibility

Has anyone used [this external RAID enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816856039)? I would like to know if it is a true hardware controller meaning Ubuntu would have no problem recognizing the array as one drive.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I have used it under 13.04 and have had no issues with the hardware itself.  I couldn't get the software that comes with the enclosure to load, but you don't need it (used gpart to configure the drive).  I've tried a couple of different RAID configurations with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured it to RAID5 (4x3Tb WDRed) using Windows software from their website and then created XFS via **mkfs.xfs /dev/sde** under 14.04 without any issues. Ubuntu detects it as a large block device, so you won't be able to see the separate drives when you have configured RAID with Cineraid utility.